# Product attribute don't save in backend

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, product-attribute, swatches

When trying to save the backend product attribute, it says saved but the same settings are there. I try to change from visual swatch to text swatch, and it saves the text swatch but doesn't update the attributes:

[image: I dont know where to start]

I dont know where I can start looking for this problem.

Comment: have You tried to clear cache  / reindex? Have you tried to disable cache?

Comment: Yes, I've all tried  this. Even in cognito is does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like core Magento bug.
Please follow https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12695